# Remove filesystem with overlay changed bytes

Tags: remote-access, sshfs

I develop a software that uses a set of big files.
I cannot download all them.
I need to reproduce timeout error that cannot be reproduce otherwise.

There are stage host. I mounted its remote folder with sshfs but I cannot launch local 
server instance because it can change these files. It requires write permissions.

With "sshfs -o ro" it fails to start.

I want to know is it possible to say to save changes locally that could overlay actual bytes in remote files?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use UnionFS or AUFS (or any other [Union mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) filesystem) to use these two folders together.  You would have the readonly mount with sshfs and merge it with local folder that would be preferred.  Reading would occur from the remote filesystem until write has been done.